# How to use index and match when you have 2 values found

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Case]

I have 2 tables: one for consults(table 1) and other as a data base(table 2).

Both tables have a "Reference" column. I wish to use the value in the "Reference" column in the table 1 to find a value in the "Reference" column in the table 2.

The table 2 has 2 more columns : "1st appearing result" and "final result". Once found the "reference" value in the table 2, I want to receive the "final result". If "final result" is empty, I want to recieve the "1st appearing result".

The real problem is that I have multiple rows in the table 2 with the same value for "Reference". Also, I have to do that without any auxiliary column.

I'll attach a pic that might help to explain.
Thanks in advance

I've tried to use lookV and index with match, but it would fly because of the multiple rows with the same value of reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a UDF? Not the most dynamic solution, but it would work for a static worksheet setup like in your example:

```
Function RETURNRESULT(refrng1 As Range, refrng2 As Range) As String

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In refrng2
        If refrng1 = cell Then
            If cell.Offset(0, 7).Value <> "" Then
                RETURNRESULT = cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
                Exit For
            ElseIf cell.Offset(0, 6).Value <> "" And finalresult = False Then
                RETURNRESULT = cell.Offset(0, 6).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

End Function
```

[image: img1]

Comment: That is great!!